DynamoDB how to update attribute with other one
I want to create a chat with AWS dynamoDB, and now I need to resolve problem with read status, when client enter chat y need to update lastReadId with msgId. DynamoDB has if_not_exist and there are path and value, I want to make something like this - update item with path
I was reading tutorials but there i didn't find information about. May be here someone can explain me solution.

Please add an example of what you're trying to achieve, I'm not sure what that is based on your current description.
